# Android error while get much info from webservice

Tags: android, byte

First my error was this one:

> Unable to resolve host “”; No address associated with
>   hostname

Then I added in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

And the error started to be this one:

> 10-29 07:18:37.078: E/Erro H:(1485): failed to connect to mywebsite.com/82.102.6.211 (port 80) after 20000ms

It downloads the bytes Images but after like 10/20 seconds it stops and gives that error.

In my manifest I currently have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I'm currently downloading bytes from Images by webservice, I'm talking about 500 images.

Could that be the problem? Thanks.

**Edit:** code to download:

```
private class productsAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try{        
            for(int i = 0; i <= all_ids.size() - 1; i++){

                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE+ "/", "get_all_products_images"); 

                request.addProperty("id", all_ids.get(i));

                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                androidHttpTransport.call(URL + "/get_all_products_images", envelope);

                SoapObject rep = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                JSONArray jr = new JSONArray(rep.getPropertyAsString(0)); 

                JSONObject jb = (JSONObject) jr.get(0); 
                byte[] theImage = jb.getString("image").getBytes(); 
                boolean isNull = (jb.getString("image") == null ? true : false);                    

                db.updateImage(theImage, jb.getInt("product_id"), isNull);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Error:", e.getMessage());
        }
        return "Executed";
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show your code where you are setting your URL and starting your request

Comment: You have to increase the Socket Time out and connection time out to open like for 40 sec 50 sec etc that will maintain the bridge and will send/receive the packet
or on the contrary use Lazy Loading to Download And Show Images 
for this Google has  defined AQuery

Comment: Yes, of course. Sorry. See my edited post.

I should set the timeout for how long? It can be downloaded like 2000 images or something..I must be prepared.
I know that the timeout is set on this line `HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);` right?